# Hover Tracking in GTM

Tags: css, google-analytics

I am trying to set up a Hover event tag in GTM without making any changes to the code on the page, so purely via GTM.

I tried using the [GTM Hover Recipe](https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2016/09/14/get-recipe-hover-tracking-google-tag-manager/) from Bounteous, but I can't seem to make the custom event fire (Step 2 in the link). I have tried to test, and the custom event tag has only fired 3 times, inconsistently.

Can we successfully track hover event tags solely on GTM or do we need to push a hover event in the data layer? Has anyone done hover tracking on GTM before?

Answer (score 0):

Your options are either using the recipe or use javascript to push the datalayer events yourself. Currently, you cannot do this without custom javascript in GTM.